# PHP redirect without #

Tags: php, redirect

After authenticating a user using Facebook OAuth, the URL comes with #*=* at the end, something like this:
[http://localhost:8000/authorize/facebook?code=aaaaaa&state=11111#*=*](http://localhost:8000/authorize/facebook?code=aaaaaa&state=11111#_=_)

I have to redirect the page to http://localhost:8000/.
I'm using header("Location: /"), but somehow the redirected page is [http://localhost:8000/#*=*](http://localhost:8000/#_=_)
I also tried header("Location: http://localhost:8000/"), got the same result though.

It doesn't affect how my application works, but I'd like to get rid of that #*=*.

Does anybody have an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you’re gonna have to do this using client-side code.

Comment: I think you need to do a client side redirect or try to avoid the hash from being inserted in the first place with e.PreventDefault() in js or something.

Hash persistency should be browser behaviour, your PHP does not actually send or do anything with the #=